# Issue listening for custom event via puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am currently working on a GitLab CI test environment and I have a test harness which we use to test our SDK. I have gone about setting up a custom event that is fired on the page which designates the end of the test run.  In my puppeteer implementation I am wanting to listen for this custom event "TEST_COMPLETE".

I have not been successful in getting this to work so I figured I would at least make sure the custom-event.js example on the puppeteer repo worked and there too I am not seeing what I believe I should be getting.  I cloned the main repo below and performed an npm install. When I execute the js test below, setting headless:false and don't close the browser, I do not see any log in console that shows any custom event being fired.

It is my understanding that I should see some console event message with 'fired' and then 'app-ready' event and info, but this is not the case. Even if I interact with the page I don't see anything outside of some 'features_loaded' and 'features_unveil' logs.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/custom-event.js

Anyone able to get the expected behavior on this code today? Not sure if this worked previously and has broke since or I am just doing something wrong. Any info would be of great help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but I can get the message '`TEST_COMPLETE fired.`' in Node.js console with this simplified code (puppeteer 8.0.0):

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  await page.exposeFunction('onCustomEvent', async (type) => {
    console.log(`${type} fired.`);
    await browser.close();
  });

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.addEventListener('TEST_COMPLETE', (e) => {
      window.onCustomEvent('TEST_COMPLETE');
    });

    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('TEST_COMPLETE'));
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Comment: Thanks @vsemozhebuty!! I have to both look into what's different here compared to their example just for my own knowledge, but I just verified with a somewhat aligned version with yours and it does in fact work, so thanks greatly!  Been messin with this since last night with no luck, so you gave me some happiness into the weekend :)

Comment: @xtr33me Happy coding and living)